# JSON.h : File not found when trying to import the JSON framework

Tags: json, ios5, xcode4.2

When i build i got that error:

```
JSON.h : File not found
```

Obvious assumptions make me think that the JSON.h file is not in the framework folder imported into my project, yes, it doesn't exist with that noun but there is a file named `SBJson.h`.
I have followed [this step by step tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) around.

Comment: No one can answer this. What framework did you import? Why do you think it should have a JSON.h?

Comment: I have downloaded it from github https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads

Comment: Then please edit your question to say, 'I downloaded this framework {url}, I followed this tutorial {url}...' Otherwise you are asking for mind-reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the JSON folder from your project and then re-add it.

When you re-add it, make sure the "Create groups for any added folders" radio button is checked.  If the other "Create folder referenes..." button is selected, it will only create a folder reference and Xcode won't know about the contents of that folder (i.e. Xcode won't "see" JSON.h).

[image: select the correct folder option]

And the resulting folder should look like this:

[image: JSON.h should be resolvable by Xcode]
(note the yellow color of the folder, indicating the "folder" is really a group)

Comment: Hi Michael, i think the author of the framework has announced that the `JSON.h` file is deprecated and it's replaced by `SBJson.h`, try to check out and please correct me if i am wrong. Go to github https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads and download an old package (example: SBJson_v3.0.4.zip), decompress it and open the `JSON.h` file in the classes folder, you can read this comment: `warning The JSON.h header is deprecated, and will disappear in a future release. Please change to include SBJson.h instead.`

Comment: if you change to import SBJson.h, is your problem solved? Makes sense about a major update to the SBJson library -- all the "errors" in my screenshots above are from ARC incompatibilities.

Comment: I have solved the ARC incompatibilities, i needed to add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to the flag compiler of each file doesn't have compatibility with the ARC. Returning to `SBJson.h`, i am currently developing a web service and will test it soon, i will let you know either it works or no.

Comment: Hi again Michael, it works with the `SBJson.h`, so this file obviously replace the `JSON.h`file, thanx for your continuous help :)