# JSON.h file not found in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json, json-lib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON.h : File not found when trying to import the JSON framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636011/json-h-file-not-found-when-trying-to-import-the-json-framework)

Currently i am working in iphone application, Using JSON Parser to parse Local JSON files, so i have import JSON library in my project, then i tried to import the JSON.h file inside the header file, but the error comes in "JSON.h file not found".
How to fix this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Below i have mentioned screen shot for your reference

[image]

Comment: remove and again add....

Comment: If the header file isn't in the project directory, you might have to set the `header search path` in the projects or target settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, itried to remove then add it, but the same error happens

Comment: How are you adding files to the project? If you are doing drag drop that will cause problems. 

You have to add them manually i.e right click on project and select add files to the project.

Comment: @fibnochi...you are wrong..we can drag and drop it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the JSON folder from your project and then re-add it.

Refer [json-h-file-not-found-when-trying-to-import-the-json-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636011/json-h-file-not-found-when-trying-to-import-the-json-framework) link.